# Magento checkout fails at /onepage/checkout stage using Internet Explorer?

Tags: internet-explorer, magento, internet-explorer-8

We've recently become aware of this problem, when clicking 'proceed to checkout' using Magento CE 1.9.0.1 and browser IE8 (may also affect other versions) I get error 'Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage'. Blank page, as though the page doesn't exist (?!)

Checkout works perfectly well in Chrome and afaik was working fine in IE until later last week. I can still access other website's carts using similar basic Magento setup and IE8.

A search hasn't shown anything relevant to my problem. Has there been any updates that may affect our checkout process?

Any advice appreciated, our developer is being less than helpful. We're losing/getting complaints from IE customers!

Cheers
H

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it appears that TLS1 was activated due to SSL vulnerabilites, this prevented IE8 from working correctly, adjusting the TLS1 settings has now enabled use of IE8.